# Battery settings seem to be missing in Cyanogenmod 13

Tags: cyanogenmod, crashes

I use Cyanogenmod 13 on my Oneplus One. When I try to access my battery settings to view the usage graph, the settings app crashes with

```
[CRASH] com.android.settings threw android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException
```

Since I don't find many results for this on the web, I assume I'm alone with that problem. How can I further debug and ideally fix this? Is there any possibility to re-upload the missing resource through ADB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I encountered the same problem. Turned out it was caused by the theme I was currently using.
You can try resetting to the default **Hexo** theme from the **Themes** app.

Comment: Fascinating, thanks for pointing out that unlikely connection! Changing back to the stock theme solved the issue. Now I'll have to try and find out where the problem actually originated, and write a bug report.

Answer (score 0):

You may have to reinstall cm13.. ohh and verify the check-sum or download another copy, not necessarily wiping data, the exception indicates that the app is missing something(or that thing is corrupt) you may also try fixing permissions if your recovery allows that